# Get Date of Birth and Gender from Google Sign in through Firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, google-signin

I'm logging in users into my Firebase app using Google / GMail login. I am then trying to get some info about the users through this API. I am able to get basic info like name and email. However, I would like to get the user's Date of Birth and Gender. I can't seem to do this through the API. I read that this might require Auth2, but since I am going through Firebase none of the tutorials seem particularly relevant. Any help would be much appreciated. Swift or Objective-c is interchangeable for me so please feel free to whichever works best for you.

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error {
    // ...
    if (error == nil) {
        GIDAuthentication *authentication = user.authentication;
        FIRAuthCredential *credential = [FIRGoogleAuthProvider credentialWithIDToken:authentication.idToken
                                         accessToken:authentication.accessToken];

        // TRYING TO GET USER INFO HERE

        NSString *fullName = user.profile.name;
        NSString *email = user.profile.email;

        // NO DATE OF BIRTH OR GENDER...

        [[FIRAuth auth] signInWithCredential:credential completion:^(FIRUser * _Nullable user, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error) {
                return;
            }
            if (user == nil) {
                return;
            }

            // UPDATE APP UI

    } else {
        // ERROR
    }
}
```